# Embedded audio player

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Our site is related to audio, yet we have no facility for playing audio here.  Coders can insert code, photographers can insert photos, but we just link to audio files.

It seems that it would be easy enough to insert a player like the [standalone version of WordPress Audio Player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone) or one of the many other flash-based players available.

Comment: Requested here: [Can an embedded audio player be added to Audio R&P?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-recording-production)

Comment: I'd actually like to be able to embed the SoundCloud player since I host all my audio files on SoundCloud to being with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Can an embedded audio player be added to Audio.SE and Music.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se) is now [status-planned](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned)!

Comment: Yeah!!  This is great news.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem we're going to have is not the player itself but storage of the files.

We currently only have the ability to upload images, I think we might need to find out if we can have some form of upload for audio, if we impose strict limits on file size (which I think is needed both to make storage less of an issue and to encourage specifity for questions).

Comment: Why not just allow linking from somewhere else then?  The audio files can be on someone's server.  Having the player here means you don't need to open up another window to hear audio, which to me is the primary benefit.

Comment: I agree that would be nice but a lot of places don't let you hot-link without using their own audio player.

Comment: Well, that is not SE's problem. If necessary, a FAQ item with recommended hosting sites for audio files could be listed.

Comment: I agree that we need more information. Someone who was involved with the private beta should probably ask about this on meta stack overflow.

Comment: Requested here: [Can an embedded audio player be added to Audio R&P?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-recording-production)

Answer (score 4):

This is now implemented as far as possible. A generic "play any file anyone could link to" is impossible (see [this answer on Meta.SO for the reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se/97610#97610)), but we now support [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com)-hosted audio tracks. A link to such a track will automatically be turned into a player:

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with this request if "own hosting" is not an option. Hotlinking often results in a high amount of dead links, which is a pain to look at, especially on a Q&A site. I have no alternative proposal, but we should really avoid questions and answers that are worthless without the audio that is accompanied with it.

Comment: Agreed, but there will be questions where the best way to communicate sound we are describing will be an audio sample.